# Sentence classification focused on specified word

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

I have passed some online courses on the sentence classification problems using TensorFlow.

But I dont understand how to start the following problem.

I am interested in the biniry classification of sentences based on the meaning of specified word. This word can have two meaning. And I want to train model which will classify it.

I have a training date. All sentences contain this word. There is labels 0 or 1 for each sentence.

Do I need a neural network for this or it can be done unisg nltk library?

How to implement such project? I have learn about word embedding. But have not idea how to use it in this project.

Where I can read about it?

Comment: Hi @Salekh, NLTK library is used for pre processing and you can use neural networks for creating a model. Please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_text_classification). Thank You.

Comment: @TFer Thank you! This link is very usefull for me.